# domain name in hebrew (punycode)

Tags: domain

Right now, my new site is running on a "dev" subdomain with no problems.
Later on, when I need to publish the final site, I will need to change the domain name to a Hebrew one (translates into punycode - xn--4dbkls9cj.co.il).
It seems like the WP system won't work with that. I've tried both to write the domain name in plane Hebrew directly and with this punycode, but nothing works.
It broke the system and I have to "recover" the original site address in the database.
So, how can I define my site to run on a Hebrew domain, as described?

Comment: "Nothing works" and "broke the system" are not informative enough. Please edit the question and add what actually is the problem....

Comment: "Nothing works" and "broke the system" mean that after making the change in both of the URLs in WP Admin, the site just doesn't come up, blank page and that's it. Only when changing the URLs back, directly in the DB, I get my site back.

Comment: so it does work, you just have server errors. look at the various error logs

Comment: where can I see those?... I don't have control over the server, it's a hosting plan. I do have FTP access and the cPanel access they provide, though.

Comment: usually they will be located at your hosting root directory, or the site root directory, but best thing is to ask for support from your hosting, especially since this might be a problem with the configuration of the web server